# Easy way to set CurrentCulture for the entire application?

Tags: .net, winforms, localization

In a .net 2 winforms application, what's a good way to set the culture for the entire application?
Setting CurrentThread.CurrentCulture for every new thread is repetitive and error-prone.
Ideally I'd like to set it when the app starts and forget about it.

Comment: This is probably old news, but it's possible to do what you want in  .NET 4.5 ([see link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.defaultthreadcurrentculture.aspx)). You probably need to set both  `DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture` and `DefaultThreadCurrentCulture`

Comment: I know this topic is quite old but all newcomers can see:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28426349/custom-format-for-entire-application

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The culture for a thread in .NET is the culture for the system (as viewed by a single application/process).  There is no way to override that in .NET, you'll have to continue setting the CurrentCulture for each new thread.

Comment: > the culture for the system
strictly speaking, the culture corresponding to the regional settings of the current user.

Answer (score 1):

You can set application current culture this way:

```
static void Main()
{
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureInfo = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fi-FI");
    Application.CurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(new Form1());
}
```

I'm not sure if it helps, because I have never tested it with threads.

edit: it doesn't work. I think you have to set current culture in every thread.

Comment: `Application.CurrentCulture` delegates to `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` so it only sets it for the main thread of the application.